# Clojure creating higher order first function

Tags: clojure

```
; Now create a function that takes a function (which produces a sequence)

; as an argument.  Your function should invoke that function and return and

; return the first element from the returned sequence.

(is (higher-order-first-function? __))
```

Guys it is actually a part of my homework. I have 1000 lines of codes to do. This is just a part that i could not figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me how to solve this ? I tried every possible way but. I could not pass the testing.

Comment: So, how do you declare a function argument? How do you invoke a function? It's not clear if you want us to help you or do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the steps are pretty clear from the comments:

1. Write a function that expects one parameter (use defn, fn, or #())
2. That parameter should be a function, so check for that (fn?)
3. Call that function
4. Return the first element in the returned sequence (first)

Comment: (fn [input-fn](+ (input-fn) 1)) I did this but it does not work. Can you give me an example please ? I am really lost. :)

Comment: So...you're calling input-fn and adding 1 to the result. That won't do it. `(fn [f] (when (fn? f) (first (f))))`

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I actually solved the problem by reading your answer over and over. :))